# Pandas installation instalsl numpy and scipy too, which I have already installed from source

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, scipy, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to install python-pandas using

```
sudo apt-get install python-pandas
```

as dependency it install numpy and scipy too. So when I import numpy and scipy now the numpy is not the development version but the one installed by the above command. How to solve it as using

```
sudo apt-get remove python-numpy
```

removes the panda too.

Comment: I don't think you should even try to do this (i.e. have custom versions of libraries that system-installed packages depend on). You are on the way to some really nasty place... If you want to experiment with different versions of Python libraries, I recommend using either virtualenv, or (maybe even better) the anaconda distribution.

Comment: I also think installing it from source will be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove ubuntu's numpy, scipy and pandas ans try using `pip` to install it:

```
sudo pip install pandas
```

Or `easy_install`:

```
sudo easy_install pandas
```

Will use the numpy and scipy you've already built (aslong as pip cand find them on $PYTHONPATH).

PS: you might need to install `pip`. You can do it from ubuntu's packages (probably `python-pip`)

Comment: thanks, although i installed it with easy_install as pip was giving Cython related errors. So add it as option in answer. Thanks again